# Genesis ROM + Level Shifter Circuit: Game Fails Without O'scope Probe

Tags: impedance, oscilloscope, level-shifting, bus, rom

**Problem:**

In an effort to learn digital electronics, I've designed and had fabricated a modern Sega Genesis cartridge. But I'm having a problem getting the cartridge to work without the help of an oscilloscope probe connected to the #CE pin. #CE is the only line which causes failure when the probe is removed, and adding the probe to any other line doesn't help.

When working (with the probe) the cartridge can play anything programmed to it, from original retail games, to test ROMs, to custom-written ROMs. Logic, art, music, input. All of it.

When not working, the cartridge successfully passes the Genesis's TMSS (their anti-unlicensed-game scheme), loads everything, starts, and then a few seconds in, music stops playing correctly. About 75% of the time, the game itself continues to play normally, but sometimes the game also freezes at the same time the music stops. The time until failure is also inconsistent, sometimes never playing any music, and sometimes failing 10+ seconds in.

**The PCB:**
[image]
In this image, the ROM is an `SST39VF3202B-70-4C-EKE` 32Mb parallel NOR ROM, and the 3 ICs are  `TI SN74ALVC164245DGGR` level shifters, 5V to 3.3V. All of them except the control section (which is set to always-outputting), are set to output when #CE is asserted. In addition, #CE itself is translated to L-#CE on the always-on Control half of the middle shifter. You'll notice several of the shifters' I/O pins are tied to ground. The datasheet requires unused pins always be tied directly to ground or Vcc. For simplicity, I chose ground.

**O'scope Readings:**

I have 2 consoles. Both can perfectly play original physical cartridges sold back in the day, such as Battletoads. The readings below are from my ROM. Yellow is #CE (0V-5V), and blue is L-#CE (0V-3.3V). Yellow looks this way regardless of the cartridge.

The first image is from the console which can only play my cartridge when the probe is attached:
[image]

The second image is from the console which can't play my cartridge at all.
[image]

**Things I've tried:**

Given that only #CE has this issue, I initially thought the level shifters were somehow interfering with #CE's ability to switch, so on one of my prototypes, I cut #CE along the below trace such that the level shifters' #OE pins were isolated but #CE was still shifted to L-#CE. I then tied the level shifters to GND and later L-#CE. Tying to GND resulted in total failure to start, and tying to L-#CE caused the original failure.

[image]

I've read that overshoot/ringing can cause unexpected switching, and is due to impedance mismatch, but I don't yet fully understand that concept and could only make crude attempts to increase the line's impedance. I've tried these things:

- 1M Ohm resistor from #CE to GND (on a cart with an uncut #CE line)
- 1M Ohm resistor and 22pF capacitor in series, from #CE to GND (on a cart with an uncut #CE line)
- 1M Ohm resistor and 22pF capacitor in parallel, from #CE to GND (on a cart with an uncut #CE line)
- 1M Ohm resistor and 100nF capacitor in series, from #CE to GND (on a cart with an uncut #CE line)
- 1M Ohm resistor and 100nF capacitor in parallel, from #CE to GND (on a cart with an uncut #CE line)
- 10 Ohm resistor from #CE to shifters' #OE (on the cart with the cut #CE line)
- 100 Ohm resistor from #CE to shifters' #OE (on the cart with the cut #CE line)

**Final notes:**

1. #CE is asserted slightly after #OE, rather than before. Generally, the assertion always lasts at least 300ns.
2. EDIT: The probe is set to 10X, but 1X also allows the cart to run fine.
3. EDIT: Connecting the probe ground only (with probe plugged into the o'scope) does not solve the problem. Connecting the probe completely without plugging into the o'scope DOES solve the problem.
4. Here's the probe's specs:

**EDIT - Full schematic:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ugh, hate those switchable probes. What attenuation is it switched to?

Comment: 10X. 1X also allows the cart to run fine.

Comment: The ringing could be due to your proving technique (hopefully you're using a spring clip), but in the second set the rise time is much shorter out of the level shifter than into it, suggesting that you've picked a faster part than the stock cartridge, which would certainly make impedance control a lot more important. I'd be tempted to have included resistors on all the outputs to slow the rise times down closer to something from the 1980s.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing them in the copped PCB picture, but you do have bypass capacitors on those (relatively fast) level translators right?

Comment: I have a cart-wide bypass cap at 47uF and one on the ROM at 1uF. I do not have any on the shifters. Should I have added some to them?

My probe has an alligator ground clip and I'm using an optional spring hook on the probe.

Comment: @Nifty255 Level shifters should probably have bypass caps too. 100 nF is probably enough. You should probably disconnect the alligator clip when using the spring ground (it'll just get in the way).

Comment: Post your schematic.

Comment: Done. Added to the end as an edit.

Comment: At first sight, looks like a mismatched impedance issue, adding some line inductance ringing. Besides trying to compensate it at the *driving* end of the line (it won't work doing the same in the middle of the track, of course), you could also add a strong pull-up on the receiver side, like 1-1.5 kOhm. Consider also that the ringing issue can be due itself to the probe, as the load capacitance with sharp edges would cause too much high currents for the driver. To test that you would have to put like a 1 kOhm series to probe (voltage precision would be affected) and or switch to 50 Ohm...

Comment: I can't say one definite problem, but the ALVC buffers are extremely fast and have extremely strong output drivers, so if your PCB wiring and bypass caps are not well designed then the chips may work erratically. And to be fair, you have long narrow supply tracks (why?) to buffers and no bypass caps (why?) at buffers. The seemingly unused copper plane seems to be 3V3 plane, as it's connected to regulator tab. Less demanding slower chips may be better to match the system around it.

Comment: The traces are thin because the pads are also thin. I saw no reason to make them thicker. They'd be even thinner if these were BGA like I want to eventually work up to for something else. As for why no bypass caps on the shifters, I'm new to this and don't know when they're needed and when they're not. I thought only the ROM would need them. I'll try the resistor testing and comment again tomorrow as it's late now.

Comment: I was slightly worried you'd skipped the second regulator cap, but you've got it and it's close-ish to the fast parts so maybe it can provide some decoupling. What I would do is probe the +5 and +3.3v pins on each chip with a spring clip to chip ground pin (shortest ground lead possible) during cart access and see how bad the power is. If it's dipping, try bodging in bypass caps until it's clean on each chip, then (with stable power) troubleshoot remaining issues.

Comment: I think adding capacitors do actually help. Being bad at soldering, I only held one onto the 5V input on one of them, but even just doing that, the ROM keeps running for several seconds longer. I'm gonna take it to a shop that can solder tomorrow and ask them to cap up the 5V inputs on all of them.